# Unable to get rows from SELECT statement

Tags: javascript, mysql, async-await, promise, node-mysql

I am using MySQL NPM package to connect to a MySQL database and trying to select a column from a table by simply invoking a query from my application. But the issue is that, I am not able to get the rows from the table at my repository level code.

First thing I have done is created a connection pool. The implementation looks like this. I create a connection pool and set `connectionPoolInitialized` as true when connetion is tested successfully.

```
const mysql = require("mysql");

export class ConnectionPool {
    private connectionPool: any;
    private connectionPoolInitialized: boolean = false;

    public async initializeConnection() {
        try {
            await this.createConnectionPool();
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    public async query(sql, args) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.connectionPool.query(sql, args, (err, rows) => {
                if (err){
                    console.log(err);
                    return reject(err);
                }
                resolve(rows);
            });
        });
    }

    private async createConnectionPool(attempt: number = 0): Promise<void> {
        if (this.connectionPoolInitialized) return;
    
        try {
            this.connectionPool = mysql.createPool({
                connectionLimit: 100,
                host: mysqlHost,
                port: mysqlPort,
                user: mysqlUser,
                password: mysqlPassword
            });
            await this.testConnection();
            this.connectionPoolInitialized = true;
            console.log("Created Connection Pool.");
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    private testConnection(): Promise<void> {
        return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
            this.connectionPool.query("SHOW DATABASES;", null, (err, rows) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else { 
                    console.log("Success.");
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I have a `BaseRepository` from where this connection pool is initialized and queries are executed.

```
export class BaseRepository {
    private readonly connectionPool: ConnectionPool;

    public async executeQuery(sql: string, values: any) {
        await this.connectionPool.initializeConnection();
        await this.connectionPool.query(sql, null)
            .then((rows) => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(rows));
                return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows));
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
                throw err;
            });
    }
}
```

And then there is actual invocation of the query through `BaseRepository`.

```
export class PersonRepository{
    private tableName: string = 'person';
    private readonly baseRepo: BaseRepository;

    public async getActivePersons() {
        const query = `SELECT 
            id 
            FROM dbName.${this.tableName} 
            WHERE isActive = 1;`;

        const rows = await this.baseRepo.executeQuery(query, null);
        console.log('Active Persons');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(rows));
    }
}
```

When `getActivePersons()` method is executed the console log in `BaseRepository` is printing all the rows as string on the console. But When it is getting returned from there to `getActivePersons()` method the console log to print the rows is printing as `undefined`.

I also tried returning the rows from `BaseRepository` without parsing it as JSON but still the result is undefined.

Is there any issue with the code? Am I missing or doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`executeQuery` doesn't return anything.

Either use the `.then()` structure and return the Promise:

```
return this.connectionPool.query(sql, null)
        .then((rows) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(rows));
            return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows));
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            throw err;
        });
```

*Or* use the `await` syntax and return the result:

```
try {
  let rows = await this.connectionPool.query(sql, null);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(rows));
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows));
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
  throw err;
};
```

But not both.  By using both you've created a structure where you await the `Promise`, but never return the result to which it resolves.

Comment: So silly of me!! 
Thanks for pointing that out!!